# Compare two lists of objects of the same type

Tags: c#

This is how the custom object is defined:

```
public class AccountDomain
{
    public string MAILDOMAIN { get; set; }
    public string ORG_NAME { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I am populating the List of objects:

```
    List<AccountDomain> mainDBAccountDomain = mainDB.GetAllAccountsAndDomains();
    List<AccountDomain> manageEngineAccountDomain = ManageEngine.GetAllAccountsAndDomains();
```

This code works fine - if I look at the locals windows I can see a List of Objects in both mainDBAccountDomain and manageEngineAccountDomain.

I'm struggling with the next bit, ideally I want a new list of type AccountDomain that contains all entries that are in mainDBAccountDomain and **not** ManageEngineAccountDomain

Any help greatly appreciated, even if it's just a pointer in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want a new list of type AccountDomain that contains all entries that are in mainDBAccountDomain and **not** ManageEngineAccountDomain

It's very simple with linq to objects, it's exactly what the [`Enumerable.Except`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779) function does:

```
var result = mainDBAccountDomain.Except(manageEngineAccountDomain).ToList();
```

You can pass a comparer to the `Except` function if you need something different from reference equality, or you could implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in `AccountDomain` (and optionally implement `IEquatable<AccountDomain>` on top of these).

See [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26202958/3764814) if you need more details about comparers.

Here's an example:

```
public class AccountDomainEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<AccountDomain>
{
    public static readonly AccountDomainEqualityComparer Instance
        = new AccountDomainEqualityComparer();

    private AccountDomainEqualityComparer()
    {
    }

    public bool Equals(AccountDomain x, AccountDomain y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
            return true;

        if (x == null || y == null)
            return false;

        return x.MAILDOMAIN == y.MAILDOMAIN
            && x.ORG_NAME == y.ORG_NAME;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(AccountDomain obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return 0;

        return (obj.MAILDOMAIN ?? string.Empty).GetHashCode()
            ^ (397 * (obj.ORG_NAME ?? string.Empty).GetHashCode());
    }
}
```

Then, you use it like this:

```
var result = mainDBAccountDomain.Except(manageEngineAccountDomain, 
                                        AccountDomainEqualityComparer.Instance)
                                .ToList();
```

Comment: At present mainDBAccountDomain has 454 objects and manageEngineAccountDomain has 3. The 3 match 3 objects in mainDBAccountDomain. I tried this and my result has 454 objects which suggests it didn't work, I would have expected 451 in the results.

Comment: That seems to work fine - I had no idea it would end up being that complex I would not have standed a chance. Thanks

Comment: Actually it would have been much simpler if you used something like `Tuple<string, string>` (but less readable). Or ReSharper, which can generate this kind of boilerplate code for you in no time. Overriding `Equals`/`GetHashCode` as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24595711/how-create-class-that-i-can-define-that-is-a-key-in-dictionary/24595967#24595967) would also need less code. The point is: you need some code that tells what *"two objects are equal"* means for your objects.